# Declare a string/word variable in C

Tags: c, variables

I'm fairly new to C, and was just wondering how to declare a word variable.

For example, while

```
int variable;
```

is able to hold only an interger value, I would like to be able to declare a variable that can hold a word, or string, e.g.

```
string name = "Joe";
```

or

```
string name = "My name is Joe";
```

However, this just crashes my program, and I'm assuming it is because `string` doesn't exist and something to do with memory-ish things.

**This is my whole code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    **string** name;

    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("Hello, %s", name);

    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you can use the array and store the sting. `char array[10]` or you can use the pointer variable. `char *string;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char name[30]; /* pre-allocated memory of stack */
```

Then scan that value in.
or

```
char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30); /* run-time allocation on heap */
```

I am just using 30 here assuming the input string fits in 30 char's you can increase or decrease it , it is up to your wish.

Comment: Thank you very much, first and correct answer will accept when I am able to. Could I ask why it is [30]? In another answer [20] was suggested, which I tried and which also worked. What is the difference, and is there a 'better' option?

Comment: @Jofish It is just the number of characters your string will hold it might be any length of your wish

Comment: @Jofish And what is the first correct answer form your perspective? (Comments included :D?)

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand... @Rizier123

Comment: @Jofish You said you accept the first correct answer, so i'm asking which is the first correct answer from your perspective? (Do you include comments :D?)

Comment: @Rizier123 On a funnier note it was my answer which was the first one :) :)

Comment: Ahhh yep you were the first one (and first correct one) but it was a comment, I was very confused there :) But I have upvoted your comment (i think?) @Rizier123

Comment: @Jofish BTW: Made a answer. So if you include comments to the "first correct answer" you can accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Declare your array as followed:

```
char name[20];
        //^^Here you can choose what you want!
```

Also i would read the string as followed:

```
scanf(" %s", &name);
     //^See the space here! The space is there so if a '\n' is still in the buffer it doesn't get read in for the name!
```

BTW: Maybe you want to take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array to store the value. Declare the array.

Like this `char name[20];`

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would store a max. 50 character long string

```
char word [50+1];
```

But if you want to define the size during runtime, use this:

```
char *word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
```

Comment: In your first example you *also* know the size in advance... I guess it depends on the definition of 'know'. And 'size'. And 'in advance'.

Comment: You're right. What I wanted to express is that in the second one, you can allocate space at runtime, but in the first one you have to define the size before compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have got two options for you.

1. statically allocated `char` array.

Example.

```
char cArray[16] = "Hello";  //will have 16 elements, initialized 5 with hello
```

or

```
char cArray[ ] = "Hello";   //number of char element is 6, considering terminating null.
```

2. a pointer to `char` variable with dynamically allocated memory.

Example:

```
char * cPtr = NULL;
cPtr  = malloc(16);    //again, 16 char elements
```

<sup>Note: A `char` array, when to be used as a *string*, MUST be null terminated.</sup>