# How do I assign multiple words in one string to individual independent variables?

Tags: c

HELP. Pls. I'm C Programming & I'm trying to assign words in a string to individual variables. Any ideas? What function can be used to do this?

For instance:

```
{
    printf("Input Full Name: ");
    string c = Get_String();

    // User inputs "Mack Moore";
    // then to achieve the below:

    string a = "Mack";
    string b = "Moore";
}
```

How do I do that pls? Break down the string & assign each word to seperate variables?

Or: If that's not possible. What I actually want is:

```
{
    printf("%c%c\n", a[0], b[0]);
}
```

to give:

```
~ MM
```

---

Please Help

Comment: Are you sure you are learning C, and not C++?

Comment: This sure looks like C++ but with a heavy C flavour. `std::cout << "Input full name: "` being C++ code. Here's some advice: C++ is a ruthlessly harsh programming language, it cares not about your pleasure as a programmer, and it's not something you can intuit without a good reference. At the absolute least you need the [C++ book by the language designer](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) to serve as an introduction, and then other books to help shore up various concepts, like how the Standard Library works. The best way to learn C++ is to be *prepared*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare a string/word variable in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547960/declare-a-string-word-variable-in-c)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I am on C at the moment, not C++.

Comment: & I deem it not appropriate for anyone to mark this as answered!.. The referred is entirely different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547960/declare-a-string-word-variable-in-c. & basic. I've been around questions asked by others on stackflow similar to this which had some answers but they were either too long & not precise so I describe my own question.

Comment: Does the input string contain only two words, or an arbitrary number of words?

Comment: 'I deem it not appropriate for anyone to mark this as answered!' well, I'm pretty sure that any C primer would answer it, as would any professional/enthusiast programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to break a string containing two words into two strings, then the solution is simple. You can use `fgets()` to get a line of input, and `sscanf()` to store the two strings in appropriate variables. Note that the `buffer` that receives input from `fgets()` is generously sized to reduce the possibility of buffer overflow. Also note that a maximum width should always be specified when using the `%s` conversion specifier to avoid buffer overflows. You should always check the value returned by the `scanf()` family of functions; here the return value is used to prompt the user to enter input again if not enough information is given.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFF_SZ  1000
#define NAME_SZ  50

int main(void)
{
    char firstname[NAME_SZ];
    char lastname[NAME_SZ];

    char buffer[1000];
    printf("Input Full Name: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);

    while (sscanf(buffer, "%49s %49s",
                  firstname, lastname) != 2) {
        printf("Please enter a first and a last name: ");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    }

    printf("Hello, %s %s\n", firstname, lastname);

    return 0;
}
```

If there is a possibility of a first, middle, and last name, this code can be modified to act accordingly. Here, the value returned by `sscanf()` is stored in `res`. If it is not `2` or `3`, the user is prompted to enter again. If the value returned was `2`, no last name was entered, so the string stored in `middlename` is copied to `lastname`, and `middlename` is changed to an empty string.

Note that this code is a little more complicated, and now the `string.h` header file has been included for the `strcpy()` function prototype.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SZ  1000
#define NAME_SZ  50

int main(void)
{
    char firstname[NAME_SZ];
    char middlename[NAME_SZ];
    char lastname[NAME_SZ];

    char buffer[1000];
    printf("Input Full Name: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);

    int res;
    while ((res = sscanf(buffer, "%49s %49s %49s",
                         firstname, middlename, lastname)) != 2 && res != 3) {
        printf("Please enter at least first and last name: ");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    }

    if (res == 2) {
        strcpy(lastname, middlename);
        middlename[0] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Hello, %s ", firstname);
    if (middlename[0] != '\0') {
        printf("%s ", middlename);
    }
    printf("%s\n", lastname);

    return 0;
}
```

For more uncertain requirements, `strtok()` may be needed to break the input string into tokens. Here an array of pointers to `char` is declared. This needs to be large enough to hold pointers to all of the words in the string, and may need to be dynamically allocated in some instances.

Here, `strdup()` is used to create a duplicate of the token returned by `strtok()`. Memory is allocated by the `strdup()` function, and it is the caller's responsibility to free it before program termination. Note that `strdup()` is not in the C Standard Library, but it is POSIX, and quite common. The first line of this program is a feature test macro that may be needed to enable use of this function. Also note that the `stdlib.h` header file has been included for the `free()` function prototype.

In all of these examples, the value returned from `fgets()` should also be checked, and in the last example it is. If there is an error in `fgets()` a message is printed and the program exits.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SZ    1000
#define MAX_WORDS  1000

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1000];
    printf("Enter a string of words:\n");
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in fgets()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *token;
    char *words[MAX_WORDS];
    char *delims = " \t\r\n";
    size_t counter = 0;

    token = strtok(buffer, delims);
    while (token != NULL) {
        words[counter] = strdup(token);
        ++counter;
        token = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        puts(words[i]);
    }

    /* Free allocated memory */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        free(words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Update

OP has mentioned a lack of familiarity with `fgets()` in comments, and that `Get_String()` is the function being used to get a line of input. `Get_String()` is not a standard C function. From the context, I suspect that this function returns a pointer to `char`, and that the function allocates memory for the string. If this is the case, these allocations will need to be freed before program termination.

It should be relatively simple to modify the above examples to use `GetString()`, though I would strongly suggest learning about `fgets()`. If `string` is an alias for `char *`, as I suspect, then you can't simply declare `string firstname;`, since this allocates no memory for the string. So, you will need to declare arrays to hold the first name and the last name. I don't guarantee this code, because I don't have access to the function `GetString()`, but the first example could probably be rewritten as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAME_SZ  50

int main(void)
{
    char firstname[NAME_SZ];
    char lastname[NAME_SZ];

    string buffer;
    printf("Input Full Name: ");
    buffer = GetString();

    while (sscanf(buffer, "%49s %49s",
                  firstname, lastname) != 2) {
        printf("Please enter a first and a last name: ");
        free(buffer);
        buffer = GetString();
    }

    printf("Hello, %s %s\n", firstname, lastname);

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `buffer` is freed before the end of the program. Also note that `buffer` is freed if input is incorrect and more input is needed. In this case, calling `GetString()` allocates new memory for `buffer`, so the old memory must be freed first. This added complexity is one reason to avoid such type aliases as `string`. The device of using `string` in place of `char *` is considered by some to be useful for teaching, but I disagree; it makes actually using strings needlessly complex and confusing. Better to learn the way that actual code is written.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! This works just fine - all I have to do is make sure I understand use of these functions used. For example; I'd been working with Get_String() not fgets, so why not & how can it work with Get_String() If it's possible; pending when I introduce myself to fgets & buffering. Thank you!

Comment: @DawnRhema-- I have added some comments about `Get_String()` and how you may be able to adapt my examples to its use.

Comment: Thanks David! learnt to use fgets & char name[100] for example. No limits. Thanks again! (y)

Comment: I'm sorry. But I already did. & tried again. Thank you for answering, but it seems I do not have enough reputation(as I am new on stackoverflow) to make that much an impact, or even vote on an answer. It just doesn't show yet. However, when I'm qualified to. I will. Thanks again!

Comment: @DawnRhema-- you have accepted now. Thanks :). When you have more reputation (15 I think), then you can upvote on questions and answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

In C a string is treated as an array of characters, so

```
"Mack Moore"
```

would be

`{'M','a','c',k',' ','M','o','o','r','e'}`

What you're looking for is called tokenization. It splits up arrays of characters based on a delimiter. It essentially replaces the delimiter (in your case a space) with a null terminator and spits out a pointer to the beginning of the split string. You then replace the input string with NULL and it will keep outputting the next delimited section until you reach the end. This code doesn't include all the needed declarations and the like. Use it only as a guide:

```
#include string.h

/*get your input string here*/

a = strtok(input, ' ');
b = strtok(NULL, ' ');

printf("%c%c\n", a[0], b[0]);
```

You can stick that strtok call in a loop if you have an indefinite amount of words in the string